# Properly throwing your own exception (make it not terminate your program)

Tags: java, exception

I have some problems throwing my own exception. Here is the code:

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    private String message;

    public MyException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Something went wrong: " + message;
    }
}
```

code where MyException is thrown:

```
static void expand(String input, String output) throws MyException {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(input));
        //do something with scanner
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new MyException("File not found!");
    }
}
```

and the main method:

```
public class Encode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
        expand("ifiififi.txt", "fjifjif.txt");
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
```

the exception is thrown normally, the message is printed normally, but the program is terminated and the "ok" message is not printed out.

```
Exception in thread "main" Something went wrong: File not found!
at vaje3.Encode.expand(Encode.java:59)
at vaje3.Encode.main(Encode.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: `expand("ifiififi.txt", "fjifjif.txt");` is not wrapped in a `try-catch` clause, so the error bubbles up to `main` and, since nothing catches it, terminates the program

Comment: Even though the exception is declared in the main method, it will still exit out. As @Michael said, since there is no try/catch around the expand, the ok is not called.

Comment: Oookay, but what do you do with try/catch in main method (over expand method)? How do you get the MyException message?

Comment: just wrap expand("ifiififi.txt", "fjifjif.txt"); in try-catch block

Comment: After declaring the said clause, in the `catch` block simply print out `exception.toString()`

Comment: So the way I created my own exception is completely wrong because I can't call the constructor MyException(String message)?, @Michael, if I do that (the second try/catch), the exception.toString() Will be null?

Comment: Like this: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fBulSV)

Comment: Ohhh, yep, all clear now, thank you. Maybe one more question, is it good practice to do your own exception the way I did it?

Comment: No, it's better to pass the message to the base Exception class in your constructor and also pass the caught exception as the cause: `super(message, e);` instead of storing the message yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are making life hard on yourself trying to cast a new exception. You dont need to do that, just pass the original up. This is better practice since the FileNotFoundException is a standard error so it is a convention shared by most programmers.

```
public class Encode {
    static void expand(String input, String output) 
    throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(input));//no try catch here or new exception
                                                  //just let the original be passed up
                                                  //via the throw directive
        //Do more here.
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
           expand("ifiififi.txt", "fjifjif.txt");
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException fnfe ){
           System.err.println("Warning File not found");
           fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know it is 100 times easier to do it this way, but we have to implement our own Exception for homework.